# Выдает ошибку при добавлении данных в таблицу php,sql

Tags: php, sql

Хочу добавить данные в таблицу, с помощью формы. Соединение с базой есть, но при добавление выдает ошибку добавления, в чем ошибся?

```
 <?php include_once("header.php");?>
<?php include_once("menu.php");?>
   <div id="content">
    <h2>Главная</h2>
  
  форма добавления данных </p>
  <form method="POST">
    <input required name="prepoduser" type="text" placeholder="Иванов"></p>
  <p>
     <input value="Добавить" type="submit"></p>
  </form>
  </p>
  
<?php
if (isset($_POST["prepoduser"])) {
      
    $conn = new data();
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Ошибка: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }  
    else {
        echo("Успешное соединение!");       
    }
        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                zanyatie (prepod) 
                VALUES (:prepod)");
                
        $data = array( 'prepod' => $_POST["prepoduser"],
        );
 
    if ( $sql->execute($data) ) {
        echo("Информация успешно занесена в базу данных!");
        }
    else {
        echo("Неизвестная ошибка добавления в базу данных!");
        }
    }
?>
  
  
   </div>
<?php include_once("footer.php");?>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос текст ошибки.

Comment: @Глеб так сложно прочитать его в коде? :)

Comment: Главных ошибок две: неправильное соединение с PDO в классе data и нелепые сообщения, которые выводит этот код. Никаких "успешно занесена" и "неведомая ошибка" этот код выводить не должен. А должен делать **перенаправление** на другую страницу (и поэтому он должен быть на самом верху страницы). И тогда в случае успеха будет перенаправление, а в случае ошибки будет выведен либо текст ошибки (в режиме разработки) либо просто 500 статус ответа (в боевом режиме) - но все это будет работать само по себе, никакой код для этого писать здесь не нужно.